# Html.DropDownList binding integers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have in my controller following code:

```
Values = new SelectList(new[] {10, 25, 50});
```

In my view I have:

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("selItemsPerPage1", Model.Items.Values,
new {
 onchange="something", title="something"
});
```

In result output it displays list of 
`System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.`

How do I make it display integers instead?

Comment: See if this fixes it : `new SelectList(new[] {"10", "25", "50"});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the controller:

```
Values = new SelectList(
    new[] 
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "10", Text = "10" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "25", Text = "25" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "50", Text = "50" },
    },
    "Value", "Text"
);
```

or if you prefer:

```
var values = new[] { 10, 25, 50 }.Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.ToString(),
    Text = x.ToString()
});
Values = new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text");
```

and in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    "selItemsPerPage1", 
    Model.Items.Values,
    new {
        onchange = "something", 
        title = "something"
    }
) %>
```